# Inside of Razer USB-C Charging Cable Layout

Tags: power-supply, laptop

maybe you can try and help ,
i got Razer Blade Stealth 13.3" QHD+ Touchscreen Ultrabook,
my charger that is 65W with 20v with 3.25a for 20v,was broken at the end of the conector at the end of the charger and when i opend to see what USB C type is it i saw 4 red lines and one blue and one more line ,
see attcehd photos and maybe you can help what needed for solder on a new C type
Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWGnl.jpg)[image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit old but I found it looking for the same answer. Hopefully the OP found their answer elsewhere. After something digging into the USB-C PD protocol, which I believe is being used here, I determined only one pinout that made sense to me. The 4 red wires should be the 4 VBUS lines required by USB PD. As far as I am aware it does not matter which VBUS plugs to which, but make no guarantee. The blue line will be CC1 of the USB-C connector, this pin is used to determine plug orientation (irrelevant here), plug connection, and power delivery negotiation. The final wire (silver, exposed) is the GND wire (connects to 4 pins in the connector).

[image: USB-C plug pinout. Pins A9, A4 (top, RTL) are VBUS, A5 is CC, A12 and A1 are GND. Pins B4, B9 (bottom, LTR) are VBUS, B1 and B12 are GND]

Pinout image and more info found at https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/introduction-to-usb-type-c-which-pins-power-delivery-data-transfer/.

I plan on using this information to fix two broken Razer USB-C 65W power supplies, but have not finished the repairs yet.